# I accidentally named a collection "stats" in MongoDB and now cannot rename it

Tags: mongodb

Oops.

I use mongoose, and accidentally created a collection "stats".
I didn't realize this was going to be an issue until a few weeks later, so I now need to rename (rather than just delete) the collection...

However, my attempts have hit a predictable problem:

```
PRIMARY> db.stats.find();
Thu Oct 18 10:39:43 TypeError: db.stats.find is not a function (shell):1
PRIMARY> db.stats.renameCollection('statssnapshots');
Thu Oct 18 10:39:45 TypeError: db.stats.renameCollection is not a function (shell):1
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try

```
db.getCollection("stats").find()
```

and

```
db["stats"].renameCollection('statssnapshots')
```

Comment: db.getCollection() is what I needed, thanks! ["stats"] did not work.

Comment: wow didn't think I would run into this kind of a problem in mongo. strange they put this method on db. Please remove the db["stats"] as that only references the build in stats function.